# Get wordpress attachments ID's separated by commas of current post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, get, attachment

i have created custom post type named "Person" and i need to get all attachments ID's separated by commas of current post in loop.

Here i have a code that loops the "person" post type posts and code that shows every posts attachments ID's, but thing is that that those ID returns like this "2713271227112710" i need it to return seperated by commas like this "2713,2712,2711,2710"

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php 
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'person',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 24,  
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="person">

    <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'person' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    ) ); ?>

     <?php
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, 'full', false );
            $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $thumbimg );

            echo $attachment_id; //here outputs the attachemnts ID's of current post
        }

    }
}
?>

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[vc_images_carousel images="'.$attachment_id.'" img_size="large" speed="3000" autoplay="yes" hide_pagination_control="yes" hide_prev_next_buttons="yes" wrap="yes"]' ); ?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php  endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
```

Comment: Why would you iterate through attachments, retrieving their URLs using their IDs, then using URLs to retrieves their IDs? use  `array_map` for `$attachments` and return $obj->ID, and then `implode()` array to string with comma as separator

Comment: Can you please write this correction in my code?

Comment: I wrote it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `implode` in combination with an `array_map`, to return an array of IDs, and then convert it to a string of IDs, separated by a comma.

So instead of this:

```
 foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, 'full', false );
            $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $thumbimg );

            echo $attachment_id; //here outputs the attachemnts ID's of current post
        }
```

Try this:

```
 $attachment_ids = implode(',', array_map(function($attachment){

          return $attachment->ID;

    }, $attachments)); 

echo $attachment_ids;
```

Comment: `<?php if ( $post->post_type == 'person' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
        $attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
        ) ); ?>
  
   <?php
        if ( $attachments ) {
        $attachment_ids = implode(',', array_map(function($obj){

        return $attachment->ID;

  }, $attachments)); 
             
        }
    }
 ?>`

Comment: you need to echo the variable

Comment: Here where im testing: [link](http://naujas.linksmaslagaminas.lt/personazai/)

Comment: @modeman, my bad, I had typo, wrong variable name, I have corrected, can you check?

Comment: Cool it works! Now can you help me to put that echo in `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[vc_images_carousel images="'.$attachment_ids.'" img_size="large" speed="3000" autoplay="yes" hide_pagination_control="yes" hide_prev_next_buttons="yes" wrap="yes"]' ); ?>`

Comment: Oh i have changed .$attachment_id. to .$attachment_ids. and it works :) Thanks again!